# StartCustomRecord does not work when making changes in two documents

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, vsto, office-interop

I wrote an code that makes changes in two Word documents in one Undo Custom Record

For example:

```vb
Sub TestUndoRecord()

    Dim objUndo As UndoRecord
    Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord
    objUndo.StartCustomRecord "TEST"

    Application.Documents(2).Activate
    Application.Documents(2).Content.Paragraphs.first.Range.Text = "1"

    Application.Documents(1).Activate
    Application.Documents(1).Content.Paragraphs.first.Range.Text = "1"

    Application.Documents(2).Activate
    Application.Documents(2).Content.Paragraphs.first.Range.Text = "2"

    Application.Documents(1).Activate
    Application.Documents(1).Content.Paragraphs.first.Range.Text = "2"

    objUndo.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

At the end of the command, three lines appeared in the cancellation list instead of one line with the word TEST.
How can this problem be solved?

My example is in VBA but I would appreciate getting an answer either in C# or in vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undo lists are document-specific: You can't have one CustomUndoRecord that covers more than one document.

It appears not to be possible to create UndoRecord lists for two documents in the same code run, whether the UndoRecord lists are nested or created and ended consecutively.

The Help topic for `UndoRecord.CustomRecordName` states:

> If custom undo records are nested within other custom undo records,
>   this property specifies what string appears on the undo stack after
>   all custom undo actions have completed. If multiple calls to the
>   StartCustomRecord method are nested, the string specified by the first
>   call will be returned by this property. If no action is active, the
>   property returns an empty string.

If the calls are not nested, but are consecutive, in my tests only the first executed line of code for the second CustomUndoRecord - created for the second document - is stored under that name. After that point, it appears the command is no longer active. And setting StartCustomRecord after that point continues to behave the same way: only one line of execution is stored in the UndoRecord, then it becomes inactive again. I also tried putting the UndoRecord code in a separate procedure - it made no difference.

Conclusion: What you're trying to do is not supported by the command.

What should work would be to create two separate instances of the Word.Application with each document opened in its own instance.